# CakePHP Paginate 2 models into 1 set of results

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

It feels like I've tried everything. I'm building a newsfeed of sorts from 2 data tables 'Spec' and 'Update'. Here is the CakePHP code.

```
// Setup pagination
$this->paginate = array(
    'Spec' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Spec.id',
            'Spec.name'
        ),
        'limit' => 10,
        'conditions' => array(
            'Spec.car_id' => $id
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'Spec.created' => $orderSetting
        )
    ),
    'Update' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Update.id',
            'Update.name'
        ),
        'limit' => 10,
        'conditions' => array(
            'Update.car_id' => $id
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'Update.created' => $orderSetting
        )
    )
);
$updates = $this->paginate(array('Spec', 'Update'));
```

This is returning an SQL error.

```
SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Update' at line 1
```

The problem is this line - it only allows for one item?
    $updates = $this->paginate(array('Spec', 'Update'));
eg.
    $updates = $this->paginate('Spec');

Which, of course, isn't what I'm looking for.

Any help or direction much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `paginate()` function does not allow multiple Models as a parameter, as it is really only a proxy to the `find()` function ([see docs](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/paginator-component#method-PaginatorComponentpaginate)). Your second parameter (`'Update'`) will be treated as a condition for the `find()` call - which results in the SQL error.

You will need to create a `find()` call on *one* model, that returns all the data you want. You can include data from the other model using model relations and possibly the ContainableBehavior.

Another way would be *two* different `find()` operations and manually combining the results. But the you would also have to handle the pagination manually.